# how to check if property for an entity exists in azure table storage

Tags: azure-storage

Below is what i want:

```
if("phone" property exists in entity){
//get value
"phone"=>$entity->getProperty("phone")->getValue();

}
```

cant find anything on azure page.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *DynamicTableEntity* class to do that. When you retrieve entities from a table without the generic TableEntity class, your entities will be of type DynamicTableEntity. This class has a property class *Properties*, which is of type *IDictionary*. So you should have code like this (I don't know if this compiles, just writing it from the top of my head):

```
if(entity.Properties.Keys.Contains("phone"))
{
var x = entity.Properties["phone"].toString() //Or cast it to whatever you need
}
```

Comment: You can find more information here: [DynamicTableEntity Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.dynamictableentity_properties.aspx)